# PHP built methods for manipulating an array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

The below is my array and I wanted to check a condition and do an array manipulation in an effective way. Which are,

1. I have to check if, `resourceContext` in the below array is `10` or `11`.
2. If it's `10` I wanted the array's name index to be replaced with
   it's own value to be.
   from `"name" => "Agency FB Bold"` to `"Agency FB Bold" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/54007"` which is `fileReference`'s value. This is because it's `resourceContext`'s value is `11`.
3. In case if it's `resourceContext` value is `10` then `"Agency FB Bold"`s index value should be  the value of `pclFontNumber` which will make the `"Agency FB Bold" => "54007"`

`$gAllFonts = array("mFontList" => array(array("name" => "Agency FB Bold", "pclFontNumber" => "54007", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/54007", "resourceContext" => "11"), array("name" => "Albertus Extra Bold", "pclFontNumber" => "53056", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/53056", "resourceContext" => "10"), array("name" => "Albertus Medium", "pclFontNumber" => "53041", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/53041", "resourceContext" => "10"), array("name" => "Antique Olive", "pclFontNumber" => "52795", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/52795", "resourceContext" => "10")));`

How this manipulation should be done using PHP built in methods?

I tried with `array pop` and `array previous` array next` but couldn't get the right way.

Comment: Can you share your expected array?

Comment: `$gAllFonts = array("mFontList" => array(array("Agency FB Bold" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/54007"), array("Albertus Extra Bold" => "53056"), array("Albertus Medium" => "53041"), array("Antique Olive" => "52795"));` Note that the `Agency FB Bold` is having a value of `fileReference` which is because it's `resourceContext` is `11`, if in case it were `10` then the value supposed to be of `pclFontNumber`'s.

Comment: I am almost done! will post the answer... in few mins. I had used `prev`, `reset` and `next`.

Comment: @SahilGulati You might want to read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792998)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$result=array();
$gAllFonts = array("mFontList" => array(array("name" => "Agency FB Bold", "pclFontNumber" => "54007", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/54007", "resourceContext" => "11"), array("name" => "Albertus Extra Bold", "pclFontNumber" => "53056", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/53056", "resourceContext" => "10"), array("name" => "Albertus Medium", "pclFontNumber" => "53041", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/53041", "resourceContext" => "10"), array("name" => "Antique Olive", "pclFontNumber" => "52795", "fontType" => "0", "fileReference" => "/var/opt/nc/downloads/52795", "resourceContext" => "10")));
foreach ($gAllFonts["mFontList"] as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value["resourceContext"] == 11)
    {
        $result["mFontList"][][$value["name"]]= $value["fileReference"];
    }
    elseif ($value["resourceContext"] == 10)
    {
        $result["mFontList"][][$value["name"]]= $value["pclFontNumber"];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: you are very fast Sahil! God given nice brain! I will post my answer too!

Comment: Yaah sure,  just after minutes, i am working on something, i will message your dont worry..

Comment: In my answer instead of using `'fileReference'` $gAllFontNameOrder[$fontOrderName] =fontSetOrderValues['fileReference'];` I would like to use `end` and `prev`. If I do that I am getting it overridden by value `11`. How to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144062/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-common-man).

Comment: @CommonMan When ever you will be free, feel free to ask..  Thanks.. :) I will surely help you with the problem you have..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
$mapping = [
    '10' => 'pclFontNumber',
    '11' => 'fileReference'
];

$gAllFonts['mFontList'] = array_map(function ($font) use ($mapping) {
    if (isset($mapping[$font['resourceContext']])) {
        $font[$font['name']] = $font[$mapping[$font['resourceContext']]];
    }

    return $font;
}, $gAllFonts['mFontList']);
```

Pay attention to `$mapping` variable. This technic gives us the ability to avoid using `if` and `elseif`.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2750933fb04c3d8c0b0dd3080935447825f629b).

**Edit:**

If you need to replace arrays wholly:

```
$mapping = [
    '10' => 'pclFontNumber',
    '11' => 'fileReference'
];

$gAllFonts['mFontList'] = array_map(function ($font) use ($mapping) {
    return [
        $font['name'] => $font[$mapping[$font['resourceContext']]]
    ];
}, $gAllFonts['mFontList']);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bec3fee06b8567c3b2d79d2a94dc7835f656f29e).

Comment: good technique! but is that replacing as expected array which i have commented below my question. I don't find it to be replaced alike expected array.